# asp-for in partial view does not generate proper id name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working with a page calling a partial view and using a model that have child objects such as Model.Child1.Child2.

My issue is that when I am passing data using the model="Model.Child1" then the Id generated are only showing the Child1 Id without including the Id of the Father. Please see below the more detailed explanation.

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<partial name="_SelectGamesPartial.cshtml" model="Model.Input.SelectGamesViewModel" />
```

The IndexModel is a PageModel that contains an object to get the data on the page called Input which contains another ViewModel called SelectGamesViewModel.

```
public partial class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }
        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            public string NickName { get; set; }

            public SelectGamesViewModel SelectGamesViewModel { get; set; }
        }
```

The SelectGamesViewModel is as follow

```
public class SelectGamesViewModel
{
        public int? GameIdSelected { get; set; }
        
        public IList<int> GamesIdAdded { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is when i pass the second view model to the partial view it doesn't map the data to the Input view.

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<partial name="_SelectGamesPartial.cshtml" model="Model.Input.SelectGamesViewModel" />
```

I  think the id that should have been generated in the partial view with the asp-for should have been something like this (id=Input.SelectGamesViewModel.GameIdSelected) but instead it just write (id=GameIdSelected)

```
<input asp-for="Model.GameIdSelected" />
```

How do you pass the model to the partial view and make sure the id is properly generated ? so the binding is happening.

Comment: i finally used the property "For" in the partial view instead of using "Model" it fixed the issue as the For will generate properly the Id assuming that we are passing a child object from the father and it needs to generate the Ids according to the father id. So the code is the following <partial name="_SelectGamesPartial.cshtml" For="Input.SelectGamesViewModel" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the id that should have been generated in the partial view with the asp-for should have been something like this (id=Input.SelectGamesViewModel.GameIdSelected) but instead it just write (id=GameIdSelected)

Firstly, `asp-for` generated the id `Input_SelectGamesViewModel_GameIdSelected` and the name is `Input.SelectGamesViewModel.GameIdSelected`.

Refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#navigating-child-properties

Then, you use `asp-for="Model.GameIdSelected"` which causes the `id=GameIdSelected`.So you need change your code like below:

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<partial name="_SelectGamesPartial.cshtml" model="Model" />
```

_SelectGamesPartial.cshtml:

```
@model IndexModel
<input asp-for="@Model.Input.SelectGamesViewModel.GameIdSelected" />
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i finally used the property "For" in the partial view instead of using "Model" it fixed the issue as the For will generate properly the Id assuming that we are passing a child object from the father and it needs to generate the Ids according to the father id. So the code is the following <partial name="_SelectGamesPartial.cshtml" For="Input.SelectGamesViewModel" />